# How to get all the "a" elements inside this div?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, google-chrome-devtools

A website on Chrome has the following structure:

```
<div class="divClass">
  <a class="aClass"></a>
  <a class="aClass"></a>
  <a class="aClass"></a>
</div>
```

I'm using JQuery to get all the "a" elements inside the div. They all have the same class. The code I'm using in the devTools is this:

```
$("div[class='divClass'] > a")
```

But it only returns the first "a" element. How can I get all of them?

Snippet:

```js
console.log($("div[class='divClass'] > a"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="divClass">
  <a class="aClass"></a>
  <a class="aClass"></a>
  <a class="aClass"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: No it doesn't. Check the snippet of your code I have attached in the question

Comment: Also note that the attribute selector is slower than the class selector, and serves no purpose here. Use `$('.divClass > a')` instead

Comment: Try `console.log($("div[class='divClass'] > a").length)` - you'll see it === 3, so all 3 have been returned in a single jquery collection.  That's how jquery works.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `$('.divClass > a')`

An alternative is to use `find()`  which gets the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements so it can be helpful here

```
$(".divClass").find("a")
```

More about `find` - https://api.jquery.com/find/

Comment: This isn't relevant to the question being asked at all. Also note that the `>` operator is not the same as jQuery's `find()` method.

Answer (score 0):

use .children method,

```
/*
var a1 = $(".divClass").children("a")[0].text;
var a2 = $(".divClass").children("a")[1].text;
var a3 = $(".divClass").children("a")[2].text; 
*/


var aaa = $(".divClass").children("a").text();
console.log(aaa);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a different selector, for instance:

```
$(".divClass > a.aClass")
```

This will find all `a` tags with class `aClass` that are immediate children of an element with class `divClass`. If you want to find all children throughout the DOM tree (i.e. grandchildren, great grandchildren, etc) then you can use omit the `>` operator.

You can then act on all elements matching these criteria (for instance `.addClass("found")`, or cycle through them individually using `.each( function() { ....})` if you need to pull element specific information from them.

The demo below is fully commented.

---

**DEMO**

```js
// Add click event to test button
$("#test").click( function() {

  // ACT ON ALL IN ONE LINE
  // Use jquery to find all direct children of elements with class divClass that are 'a' tags with class 'aClass'
  // Add red border using CSS styles
  $(".divClass > a.aClass").addClass("directChildren");
  
  // Find grandchildren, great grandchildren, etc
  // Turn color of text blue using CSS
  $(".divClass a.aClass").addClass("allChildren");
  
  // HOW TO CYCLE TRHOUGH EACH LINK
  // Cycle through each, find them using same technique as above 
  $(".divClass > a.aClass").each( function() {
  
    // Prove we've found each individual link
    console.log($(this).text());
    
  });
  
});
```

```css
.directChildren {
  border: red 2px solid;
}

.allChildren {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="divClass">
  <a class="aClass">Link 1</a>
  <a class="aClass">Link 2</a>
  <a class="aClass">Link 3</a>
  
  <div style="padding:12px;">
    <a class="aClass">Grandchild Link 1</a>
  </div>
  
</div>

<button id="test">Find Children</button>
```